# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for student-service at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul

I am running the **Spring Cloud Consule** example from link::**https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-cloud/consul-service-registration-discovery/**. When I am running the http://localhost:8098/getSchoolDetails/abcschool I am getting the below error, it seems that client is unable to recognized the `student-service`.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances available for student-service
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerInterceptor.intercept(LoadBalancerInterceptor.java:55) ~[spring-cloud-commons-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:1.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:86) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.intercept(MetricsClientHttpRequestInterceptor.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:86) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:652) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:559) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.example.howtodoinjava.springcloudconsulschool.delegate.StudentServiceDelegate.callStudentServiceAndGetData(StudentServiceDelegate.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.howtodoinjava.springcloudconsulschool.controller.SchoolServiceController.getStudents(SchoolServiceController.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

When I checked the instance both services are registered in Consul at :   http://localhost:8500/ui

[image]

**StudentServiceDelegate**

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceDelegate {
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String callStudentServiceAndGetData(String schoolname) {
        System.out.println("Consul Demo - Getting School details for " + schoolname);
        String URL = "http://student-service/getStudentDetailsForSchool/{schoolname}";

        String response = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {}, schoolname).getBody();


        System.out.println("Response Received as " + response + " -  " + new Date());

        return "School Name -  " + schoolname + " :::  Student Details " + response + " -  " + new Date();
    }

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

In the above controller when calling rest call, its failing there.

**SchoolServiceController**

```
@RestController
public class SchoolServiceController {

    @Autowired
    StudentServiceDelegate studentServiceDelegate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getSchoolDetails/{schoolname}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStudents(@PathVariable String schoolname) {
        System.out.println("Going to call student service to get data!");

        return studentServiceDelegate.callStudentServiceAndGetData(schoolname);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=8098
spring.application.name=school-service
management.security.enabled=false
```

**Added SH-1**

[image]

**Added SH-2**

[image]

> **Get http://XXXX.com:8098/health: dial tcp 10.142.167.39:8098: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.**

When I hit **http://localhost:9098/health**, I get the below error.

```
{
    "status": "DOWN",
    "discoveryComposite": {
        "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client",
        "status": "UP",
        "discoveryClient": {
            "description": "Spring Cloud Consul Discovery Client",
            "status": "UP",
            "services": [
                "consul",
                "school-service",
                "student-service"
            ]
        }
    },
    "diskSpace": {
        "status": "UP",
        "total": 511584497664,
        "free": 336424210432,
        "threshold": 10485760
    },
    "refreshScope": {
        "status": "UP"
    },
    "consul": {
        "status": "DOWN",
        "services": {
            "consul": [],
            "school-service": [],
            "student-service": []
        },
        "error": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must not be null"
    },
    "hystrix": {
        "status": "UP"
    }
}
```

Comment: See that your services registration is failing for health check I guess. Mind the "1 failing".

Comment: when u hit http://localhost:<your_port>/health endpoint on browser.. do u see proper response?

Comment: Updated post, "error": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value must not be null", but why ? I uploaded my code at https://github.com/test512/spring-cloud-howtodoinjava/tree/master/Consul%20Service%20Registration%20and%20Discovery%20Example

Comment: I just followed the tutorial you mentioned and everything is working fine for me.. When you start your application you must see this line "main] o.s.c.c.s.ConsulServiceRegistry          : Registering service with consul: NewService{id='student-service-9098', name='student-service', tags=[],............." In this line you also get health endpoint which you can hit to see the response.

Comment: agree. Its working fine for you, but for me its still not working. I clean the project loaded and compiled again..not sure whats going on.. Registering service with consul: NewService{id='student-service-9098', name='student-service', tags=[], address='test.us.test1.com', port=9098, enableTagOverride=null, check=Check{script='null', interval=10s, ttl=null, http=http://test.us.test1.com:9098/health, tcp=null, timeout=null, deregisterCriticalServiceAfter=null, tlsSkipVerify=null}, checks=null}

Comment: https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-consul-example/blob/master/client/README.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fixed this issue as per this link : https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-consul-example/blob/master/client/README.md, we should strictly used below properties to avoid below error.

```
management.security.enabled=false
management.health.consul.enabled=false
```

[image]

[image]

```
http://localhost:8098//getSchoolDetails/abcschool
```

The output I get is::

```
School Name - abcschool ::: Student Details [{"name":"Sajal","className":"Class IV"},{"name":"Lokesh","className":"Class V"}] - Thu Apr 12 15:47:53 IST 2018
```

Comment: Glad to know that you fixed your issue by urself. I ran your code and it worked for me. So the only difference I can think of is that You must be using the latest version of Consul and I am using 0.7.2 version.

Comment: I am using consul version 1.0.6. Lot more questions I will raised soon :)